# Can you define a resolve function for Promises?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting up to speed with Promises, but there's one thing I don't understand.

So, we define a Promise like so:

```
new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );
```

I was under the impression that `resolve` is a function that I should call when the situation is resolved successfully. So I tried to do something like this:

```
function resolve(number) {
  return number * 2;
}

var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(5), 1000);
});

p.then((doubledNumber) => {
  console.log(doubledNumber); // expected: 10, actual: 5
});
```

So it seems like `resolve` isn't a function in the usual sense, it's more like a keyword like `return`. In other words, when I'm calling `resolve`, I'm just instructing the program to pass on whatever value is that I provide as the arg to `resolve`.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That understanding is not quite correct. The `resolve` function you define is not being used. When you call `resolve(5)`, you're instead using the `resolve` function that's being provided as an argument by the Promise constructor. **The name `resolve` has no special meaning**, you can use any name you want for this argument. For example, instead of `resolve` and `reject` we could call them `setValue` and `setError`:

```
var p = new Promise((setValue, setError) => {
  setTimeout(() => setValue(5), 1000);
});
```

You can see here why the function you defined called `resolve` was not being used when it was shadowed by the local definition of `resolve`.

The `resolve()` function you're given by the Promise constructor is only called by you, to provide a value to the Promise.

If you want to modify the value resulting resulting from a Promise, you need apply your filtering function using `.then(...)` (which gives you a new Promise with the modified value):

```
function doubleResult(x) {
  return x * 2;
}

var doubleP = p.then(doubleResult);
doubleP.then((doubledNumber) => {
  console.log(doubledNumber);
});
```

Comment: OK, the bit about the function name getting shadowed by the arg name is what clicked for me. So to "process" the returned value I suppose I could also define the function like `function r(val) { return val * 2; }` and then call it in the Promise like `setTimeout(() => resolve(r(5)), 1000)`.